# vimdiff: start in second split?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

When using vimdiff, I'd like to start in the second pane (my changes), instead of the first.

I've tried adding this to my .vimrc, but it doesn't seem to work.  Is there a different event I should be hooking?

```
if &diff
  autocmd BufWinEnter * winc l
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
if &diff
  autocmd VimEnter * normal ^W^L
endif
```

Note here that `^W` and `^L` are single characters. You can enter them using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Comment: Thanks; works great!  Looks like "autocmd VimEnter * winc l" also works: I guess "BufWinEnter" was the problem.

Comment: Yup. I just wanted to do it my way. I didn't know about `winc` Thanks for helping me learn that